# Рекурсивный алгоритм подсчета ежемесячной капитализации по вкладу

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.x, рекурсия

Не получается придумать рекурсивный алгоритм. Подскажите его, пожалуйста.

*Задача:*
Капитализация по вкладу происходит каждый месяц. Получить рекурсивно конечную сумму вклада и прибыль (разность между начальной и конечной суммой вклада).

Функцию, рекурсивно считающую с ежегодной капитализацией написал, но не пойму, как написать с ежемесячной.

Код:

```
def recursive_method(StartDeposit,RateInYear, TotalAmountYear):
    if (TotalAmountYear == 0): return StartDeposit
    return recursive_method(StartDeposit,RateInYear, TotalAmountYear-1)*(1+RateInYear/100)
```

***Решение:***

```
def recursive_method(StartDeposit,RateInYear, TotalAmountYear):
    AmountMonth = 12* TotalAmountYear
    def forMonth(StartDeposit,RateInYear, AmountMonth):
        if (AmountMonth == 0): return StartDeposit
        return forMonth(StartDeposit,RateInYear, AmountMonth-1)*(1+RateInYear/100/12)
    profit = forMonth(StartDeposit,RateInYear, AmountMonth)
    print("Полученная прибыль: ",  profit - StartDeposit)
    print("Итоговая сумма вклада: ", profit)
```

Comment: Сейчас обнаружил, что подобный алгоритм так же разбирали здесь http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840226/python-recursion-with-compound-interest

но тоже с годовым, а не месячным начислением процентов.

Comment: @LEQADA, это я уже нагуглил метод и название здесь озвучил просто.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Передаёте начальный депозит, процентную ставку(месячную), количество лет.
Получаете на выходе конечную сумму и прибыль.

```
def total_profit(StartDeposit, RateInMonth, TotalAmountYear):
    TotalAmount = 12 * TotalAmountYear
    def recursive_method(StartDeposit,RateInMonth, TotalAmount):
        if (TotalAmount == 0): return StartDeposit
        return recursive_method(StartDeposit,RateInMonth, TotalAmount-1)*1+RateInMonth/100)
    total = recursive_method(StartDeposit,RateInYear, TotalAmount)
    return total, total - StartDeposit
```

Comment: Я немного модифицировал Ваш код, но понял алгоритм. Спасибо большое, Вы мне  очень помогли.

Answer (score 2):

Рискну предположить:

- `StartDeposit` - начальная сумма
- `RateInYear` - годовая ставка
- `TotalAmountMonth` - количество месяцев

  ```
  def recursive_method(StartDeposit,RateInYear, TotalAmountMonth):
      if (TotalAmountMonth == 0): return StartDeposit
      return recursive_method(StartDeposit,RateInYear, TotalAmountMonth-1)*(1+RateInYear/(12*100))
  ```

Comment: Не совсем то. Вы модифицировали мой вариант, вместе кол-ва лет передали кол-во месяце и соотвественно поделили. Я тоже это сделал(подробно этот алгоритм объясняют на ИНТУИТ). Скорее даже совсем не то.

Comment: Ваш вопрос:
"_Функцию рекурсивно считающую с ежегодной капитализацией написал, не пойму, как написать с ежемесячной._"

Уточните пожалуйста, что вы подразумевали.

Comment: @ВладиславМСК Ну почему же не то? Эта функция считает величину вклада через `TotalAmountMonth` месяцев, с учетом ежемесячной капитализации. Все правильно

Comment: @tutankhamun, 1. Передается кол-во лет, а не месяцев (можно передавать аргумент умноженный на 12, но это костыли). 
2. Функция не считает прибыль.

Comment: А алгоритм простой. Если количество месяцев равно 0 - сумма равна начальному вкладу, если больше нуля - сумма равна сумме предыдущего месяца умноженной на 1 + "месячный" процент. Вот вам условия для рекурсии (причем первое условие является условием выхода из рекурсии)

Comment: @ВладиславМСК Зачем вы так? Вам нужна функция, которая сразу возвращает и конечную сумму и прибыль? Значит нужно переделать функцию, чтобы она возвращала список, а сумму она считает правильно

Comment: @tutankhamun, это не альтернативное решение. Вы модифицировали решение представленное мной. Оно не считает прибыль.

Comment: ВладиславМСК, Я правильно понял что вам нужно получить именно прибыль?А не конечную сумму?

Comment: @ivanK., Функция в питоне может возвращать 2 значения. Нужно  вернуть конечную сумму и прибыль(разность между начальной и конечной). И функции передается кол-во лет, а не месяцев.

Comment: ВладиславМСК, а при чем тогда Ваш вопрос о помесячной капитализации???

Comment: @ivanK, начесление процентов идет каждый месяц, а не каждый год.

Comment: @ВладиславМСК, т.е. передается не годовая ставка, а месячная?

Comment: @ВладиславМСК 1. Я ничего не модифицировал; 2. В вашем вопросе формулировка "...не пойму, как написать с ежемесячной". На этот вопрос вам ответили; 3. По поводу того, что должно _обязательно_ передаваться количество лет в вопросе ни слова. Пожалуйста, оставьте эмоции и, если видите, что вас не понимают - переформулируйте более точно вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Вообще ежемесячная капитализация должна быть [фиксированной](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4), она расчитывается как годовая капитализация деленная на 12 и поэтому никакой рекурсии не требуется.

Но в вашем учебном задании видимо имеется в виду что проценты начисляются каждый раз от предыдущей суммы

```
def recursive_method(deposit, percent_in_year, months):
    if (months == 0): return deposit
    capital = deposit * percent_in_year / 1200
    return recursive_method(  deposit + capital
                            , rate_in_year
                            , months - 1)
```